# Layout and Drawables for Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have my layouts in

```
layout/main.xml
```

Now Nexus S is 4 inch and Galaxy nexus is 4.65 inch. Drawables are placed in

```
drawable-xhdpi
```

for galaxy nexus for Nexus S i am not sure where to put drawables.

I want different images based on the device so in xml where to place images that i can use in nexus S 4 inch device???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus s is 233 ppi, so it will fit on hdpi

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview

Comment: i have tried putting my drawables in there but still image in xhdpi folder on drawable folder is being displayed

Comment: Hmmm, how exactly do you check that is the wrong image being displayed?

Comment: i have given the same name to another image and placed that in drawable-xhdpi and another in drawable-hdpi :P ,, anyhow there was something silly ,, sorted that out,, U wr absolutely ryt about hdpi Spot on . Thnx figured it out.

Comment: changed another image and checkout other one :D

Answer (score 1):

Nexus S is hdpi device so put it in hdpi devices.
And you need to re scale the images accordingly

Comment: already placed it there but somehow it isnt picking the ryt drawables . Can there be something else that might be causing this problem?

Comment: did u checked the path in xml about it?